# Get Caller Class In Python

Tags: python, odoo

I've a class calling another class's function, like this:

```
self.pool.get('some_value')
```

How do I get the caller class inside the get function ?

thanks before,

Comment: Do you want the caller class or the caller object? Why do you need this? And why can't you pass it in as a parameter to the called function (callee)?

Comment: You mean the caller object reference, right? Or do you mean the actual class name that was used to instantiate the caller object?

Comment: Anyway, this could be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065086/how-to-get-the-caller-class-name-inside-a-function-of-another-class-in-python

Comment: @batbrat: I can't, the function is being used alot, it's impossible to add another parameter to the function

Comment: @Lawrence: I want to get the object reference, is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this via `inspect`. The contents of the `get()` function can be:

```
import inspect
myCaller = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals['self']
```

After that, you have the caller's instance refered to by `myCaller`.

**Disclaimer**: this is **not** a good practice, because it ruins the whole point of encapsulation.

Comment: great answer, especially the disclaimer. Is it possible for this approach to fail/break under any circumstances that you know of? It looks standard, so I suppose it shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks. I do not know of such circumstances, but then again, I avoid these kind of solutions so I haven't exactly tested it extensively.

Comment: Thx @Lawrence, I've finally found the class that I want using inspect,
but it seems to be a performance hog, but I'll still use it.
please tell me if u've a better solution, thanks :)

Comment: I guess it should typically be avoided in code / projects that are not internals-laden by nature