# How to get class name from bound method using inspect?

Tags: python, stack, stack-trace, classname, inspect

```
class MyClass:
  def my_method(self):
    print(get_context())

MyClass().my_method()
```

I need get next line:

```
MyClass::my_method
```

sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name gives me only "my_method". How to get also class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your classname by calling `__class__.__name__` from `self`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

Foo().bar()
```

Output:
Foo

Comment: No. The get_context() function does not knows about "self"

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you have control over that method? Can you pass parameters to that method? You *could* pass "self" to the method and you will have the information you need as well?

Comment: Take a look at this. I think this is what you are looking for: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065086/how-to-get-the-caller-class-name-inside-a-function-of-another-class-in-python

Comment: I took out the `B` method from the class on its own and it worked. That should be it I believe.

Comment: This is necessary for debug purposes with simple syntax:
for example: INFO_MSG("Hi!")
>> MyClass::MyMethod  INFO:  Hi!

Thaks! Answer above helped me.