# Get name of module that is instantiating my class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am editing some code that is being called by another system that I do not control. This system initializes my class from a few different places. I need to perform different things depending on where my class is called from.
Is there a way I can find where my object is being initialized?

`A.py`:

```
class InitializerA:
    def calling_function(self):
        Called()

class InitializerB:
    def calling_function(self):
        Called()
```

`B.py`:

```
class Called:
    def __init__(self):
        # I want to know here whether it is being called by InitializerA or InitializerB
```

Comment: Why do you want that? What's the context in which that would be useful?

Comment: Called can do different things depending on who is calling it. Unfortunately, this is some legacy code that needs to be modified, and I cannot add a new argument to the initializers.

Comment: That seems like a terrible design, what has led to that? How is it currently handled?

Comment: Agreed, this is not ideal. Initially, Called would do the same thing for all the Initializers, but due to a change in business requirements, it now needs to do different things.

Comment: You'd probably be better off making specific subclasses of called for each initializer if that would be possible

Comment: Your requirements don't make much sense to me. If you're refactoring to add new functionality, why the limits on what you can change to get there? Please [edit] the question to provide more useful context, this seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I've added some context. The calling code is a different system that I cannot modify.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the answer by modifying the method given in this question:
[How to get the caller class name inside a function of another class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065086/how-to-get-the-caller-class-name-inside-a-function-of-another-class-in-python)

The `inspect` library helped me inspect the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the class initializing it as an parameter to Called i.e:

```
class class InitializerA:
def calling_function(self):
    Called(self.__name__)


class Called:
def __init__(self, initializer):
     self.initializer = initializer
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is some legacy code that needs to be modified, and I cannot add a new argument to the initializers.