# get a class name of calling method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know how to get a caller method name (from here: [How to get the caller's method name in the called method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654113/how-to-get-the-callers-method-name-in-the-called-method))

```
import sys
print sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name
```

What I'd like to get is the class name this method belongs to (assuming that it is in the class). 
So if:

```
def get_some_info():
    print('Class name of caller:', XXX)

class Base:
     def my_method(self):
         get_some_info()

class A(Base):
     pass

class B(Base):
     pass

a = A()
b = B()
a.my_method()
b.my_method()
```

should return:

```
 ... A
 ... B
```

What should I do in `xxx`?

I tried (using info on `_getframe`) do something like:

```
 sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.__self__
```

but it doesn't work

UPDATE:

I cannot pass class name to a called function (otherwise that would be easy, but thanks to all who suggested this solution!)

Comment: Why don't you make your `get_some_info` a class method and print out the `self.__name__` variable? It should give you the class name....

Comment: @toti08 or If its needs to be instance method he can call `self.__class__.__name__`

Comment: Wow your question is misleading. You aren't looking for the class where the calling method was defined. You're looking for the class of the `self` variable...

Comment: @Aran-Fey: yes, that's why in an output I'd like to get, I mentioned that it should be `A` or `B`, not `Base`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the calling frame object with [`inspect.currentframe()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.currentframe) and get the object that `self` is bound to through its `f_locals` attribute:

```
import inspect

def get_some_info():
    # get the call frame of the calling method
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    try:
        # try to access the caller's "self"
        try:
            self_obj = frame.f_locals['self']
        except KeyError:
            return None

        # get the class of the "self" and return its name
        return type(self_obj).__name__
    finally:
        # make sure to clean up the frame at the end to avoid ref cycles
        del frame
```

The disadvantage of this is that it relies on the first parameter to be named "self". There are a few cases where we use different names, for example when writing a metaclass:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        get_some_info()  # won't work!
```

And if you have a function with a `self` variable, it can produce unexpected results:

```
def not_a_method():
    self = 3
    print(get_some_info())  # output: int
```

We can solve both of these problems, but it takes a lot of work. We can inspect the name of the "self" parameter through the calling code object's `co_varnames` attribute. And in order to check whether the calling function is really a method defined in a class, we can loop through the `self`'s MRO and try to find the method that called us. The end result is this monstrosity:

```
def get_some_info():
    # get the call frame of the calling method
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    try:
        # find the name of the first variable in the calling
        # function - which is hopefully the "self"
        codeobj = frame.f_code
        try:
            self_name = codeobj.co_varnames[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

        # try to access the caller's "self"
        try:
            self_obj = frame.f_locals[self_name]
        except KeyError:
            return None

        # check if the calling function is really a method
        self_type = type(self_obj)
        func_name = codeobj.co_name

        # iterate through all classes in the MRO
        for cls in self_type.__mro__:
            # see if this class has a method with the name
            # we're looking for
            try:
                method = vars(cls)[func_name]
            except KeyError:
                continue

            # unwrap the method just in case there are any decorators
            try:
                method = inspect.unwrap(method)
            except ValueError:
                pass

            # see if this is the method that called us
            if getattr(method, '__code__', None) is codeobj:
                return self_type.__name__

        # if we didn't find a matching method, return None
        return None
    finally:
        # make sure to clean up the frame at the end to avoid ref cycles
        del frame
```

This should handle pretty much everything you throw at it correctly:

```
class Base:
    def my_method(whatever):
        print(get_some_info())

    @functools.lru_cache()  # could be any properly implemented decorator
    def my_decorated_method(foo):
        print(get_some_info())

    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls):
        print(get_some_info())

class A(Base):
    pass

def not_a_method(self=3):
    print(get_some_info())

A().my_method()            # prints "A"
A().my_decorated_method()  # prints "A"
A.my_class_method()        # prints "None"
not_a_method()             # prints "None"
print(get_some_info())     # prints "None"
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `inspect.stack()`:

```
def get_some_info():
    _stack = inspect.stack()[1]
    print ('cls:', _stack[0].f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__, 'func:', _stack[3])

....

a = A()
b = B()
a.my_method()
b.my_method()
```

Prints:

```
('cls:', 'A', 'func:', 'my_method')
('cls:', 'B', 'func:', 'my_method')
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for classmethods and staticmethods (nor plain functions obviously)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Well, the OP *is* looking for the type of `self`, so that's a given...

Comment: @Aran-Fey indeed, but I thought it was worth mentionning nonetheless.

Comment: `self` is not actually required to be called `self`, but I've never seen a case where it isn't, aside from exercises contrived to showcase the possibility. Well, that and metas.