# Unable to inspecting class name for caller class methods with @staticmethod decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-inspect

Trying to use [How to get the caller class name inside a function of another class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17065086/how-to-get-the-caller-class-name-inside-a-function-of-another-class-in-python) I ran into a peculiar issue with decorated methods.

`stack[1].frame.f_locals["self"].__class__.__name__` works in case of instance method call but when applying over class methods (function with `@staticmethod` decorator) it throws an error:

```
src = '<{}>.'.format(stack[1].frame.f_locals["self"].__class__.__name__)
KeyError: 'self'
```

The code is given below (working for instance method with `self` param but nor for `@staticmethod` decorated class methods):

```
def some_func():
    '... some_code ...'
    import inspect
    stack = [x for x in inspect.stack() if 'My_Module' in str(x)]
    try:
        src = '<{}>.'.format(stack[1].frame.f_locals["self"].__class__.__name__)
    except:
        from traceback import format_exc
        print(format_exc())
        src = ''
   '... some_code ...'

class SomeClass:
    @staticmethod
    def tester():
        some_func()
```

Any clues?

Comment: I thinks it depends on how your caller class, for example, `def run(self):` should be works but `def eval_bob(cls):` does not. In this case, your `some_func` does not declare `self`.

Comment: Sorry - my fault - i wanted to inspect a static method - corrected the question

Comment: What if you have `class Foo: ...; def bar(): some_func(); Foo.foo = bar; Foo.foo()`? What do you want as a result in this case?