# Logging Formatter record current function executing

Tags: python, logging

In my python logging I want to record the function currently executing/running. For example;

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
       logging.info("I'm alive") # Writes to log: '[INFO]: Foo::bar(), I'm alive'
```

Is it possible to configure my logger to do this? Ie, create a formatter to find this out?

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(FUNCTION_NAME)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding the information context to the `record` of the logger. To do this, you need to define your own `ContextFilter` class and add an instance of it to your logger. Notice that in order to get the class name, we depend on the convention of calling `self` the instance of a class, and not using it as arguments of other functions (It is based on this SO question [how-to-retrieve-class-information-from-a-frame-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203424/python-how-to-retrieve-class-information-from-a-frame-object)). Notice also that this work-around is not able to determine the class of `internalFunc` because it does not have the `self` argument. See the code below.

```
import inspect
import logging


def get_class_from_frame(fr):
    args, _, _, value_dict = inspect.getargvalues(fr)
    if len(args) and args[0] == 'self':
        instance = value_dict.get('self', None)
        if instance:
            return getattr(instance, '__class__', None)
    return 'NOCLASS'

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    """
    This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.
    """
    def filter(self, record):
        #we are adding the function field to the logger record     
        mystack = inspect.stack()[5]
        record.function = '%s::%s'%(get_class_from_frame(mystack[0]), mystack[3])
        return True

def buildLogger():
    logger = logging.getLogger("root")
    #now we use the function field in the format
    myFormat = '[%(levelname)s] %(function)s: "%(message)s"' 
    formatter = logging.Formatter(myFormat)
    # add an instance of ContextFilter to the logger    
    myFilter = ContextFilter()
    logger.addFilter(myFilter)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.propagate = False
    return logger

# Some testing

def myStandaloneFunction():
    logger.warning('this is logged from myStandaloneFunction')

class A():
    def afunc(self):
        def internalFunc():
            logger.warning('this is logged from inside internalFunc call')
        logger.warning('this is logged from inside a afunc call')
        internalFunc()


logger = buildLogger()

logger.warning('this is logged from module level')
myStandaloneFunction()
a = A()
a.afunc()
```